# Columns and their types for shapefile in OGR/python

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, ogr

I am trying to list all the columns (or features) and their types for a shapefile. 
shp2pgsql shows following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "liberia" (gid serial,
"local_name" varchar(100),
"eng_name" varchar(100),
"cntry_name" varchar(75),
"type" varchar(75),
"cntry_code" varchar(10),
"continent" varchar(50),
"iso_code" varchar(10),
"volume" int4,
"id_7_1" varchar(100),
"id" numeric(10,0));
ALTER TABLE "liberia" ADD PRIMARY KEY (gid);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','liberia','geom','5578','MULTIPOLYGON',2);
```

The following code snippet tries to achieve that:

```
 from osgeo import ogr
 reader = ogr.Open("file.shp")
 x = reader.GetLayer(0)
 fields  = x.schema
 for l in ll:
    print l.GetName()
    print l.GetType()
```

Which prints output as follows:

```
LOCAL_NAME
4
ENG_NAME
4
CNTRY_NAME
4
...
```

I am facing two problems. One the geom column/feature is missing from the list and second deciphering type id to python or postgres type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will address the problems seperately:

**Type of shapefile column**

The `schema` function is actually a wrapper around the `GetFieldDefn()` and `GetLayerDefn()` functions:

```
output = [] 
defn = self.GetLayerDefn() 
for n in range(defn.GetFieldCount()): 
    output.append(defn.GetFieldDefn(n)) 
return output
```

([source code](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr-pysrc.html#Layer.schema))

The individual entries `l` you iterate over are therefore instances of `OGRFieldDefn` ([Documentation](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRFieldDefn.html)). They have a function called `GetFieldTypeName(Type)` that you can use:

```
for l in ll:
    type = l.GetType()
    type_name = l.GetFieldTypeName(type)
    print type_name
    print l.GetName()
```

**Accessing the geometry**

You can iterate over the features in a shapefile as usual:

```
from osgeo import ogr
reader = ogr.Open("file.shp")
for feat in reader.GetLayer():
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    # geom is now an ogr geometry object
    print geom.ExportToWkt()
```